# Use keyframes to change the width of an SVG while keeping it static on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I am attempting to animate an SVG. In the example below, the pink square moves 50px to the right. I am attempting to make the orange rectangle's right side grow to match the location of the pink square (so they are flush), while keeping the rest of the orange square static.

The animation currently goes for two seconds (two full cycles) when the button is pressed. I have attempted to use `scale()` and `translate()`. From my understanding:

- `scale()` is designed to change the size of the shape equally.
- `translate()` is designed to move the entire shape around on the page.

I have also attempted to change the `width` of the orange rectangle, but I believe that this is incorrect because that property is not a `transform` property.

Thanks!

```js
function startAnimation(time) {
  document.getElementById("pink").style.animation =
    "slide 1s ease forwards infinite";
  document.getElementById("orange").style.animation = "grow 1s ease forwards infinite";

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("pink").style.animation = "";
    document.getElementById("orange").style.animation = "";
  }, time);
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#svg5 {
  width: 75vh;
  height: auto;
}

#pink,
#orange {
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate(none);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(none);
  }
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    /* ? */
  }
  50% {
    /* ? */
  }
  100% {
    /* ? */
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>SVG Grow</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" id="svg5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="canvas" transform="translate(5 -165)"><g id="pink"><path id="pink-box" fill="#ff00e2" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width=".214" d="M105 255h20v20h-20z"/></g><g id="orange"><path id="orange-box" fill="#ff9300" stroke-width=".755" d="M65 257h40v15H65z"/></g></g></svg>
  </svg>

  <button id="animation" onClick={startAnimation(2000)}>Animate!</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: After looking at the example more, the shapes used do appear somewhat phallic. The intent is for the orange to be a laser and the pink to be a mirror. As the mirror moves, the laser moving towards the mirror would also move